# How to Compress and reduce Quality of image using Glide for android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm using Glide library to upload images.  In another app, I use this code

```
void imageButtonclick() {
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CropImage.activity(filePath).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1).setOutputCompressQuality(50).start(UploadBook.this);

                // Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageuri);
                    //startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

to decrease the size of the image by declaring `.setOutputCompressQuality(50)` But I don't know how to do the same with the Glide Image library.

My code is

```
public static void loadLocalImage(Context ctx, RequestOptions glideRequests, Uri uri, ImageView imageView,
                                      RequestListener listener) {

        glideRequests.fitCenter()
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);
        Glide.with(ctx)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(glideRequests.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).error(R.drawable.ic_stub))
                .asBitmap()
                .load(uri)
                .listener(listener)
                .into(imageView);

    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Glide official site](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#bitmap-format):

> By default Glide prefers RGB_565 because it requires only two bytes
>   per pixel (16 bit) and therefore has half the memory footprint of the
>   higher quality and system default ARGB_8888.

So you cannot reduce the quality of a bitmap anymore, but you have some another options.

**Option 1**: Resizing image size with `override(x, y)`.

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .override(100, 100);

Glide.with(fragment)
    .asBitmap()
    .apply(myOptions)
    .load(url)
    .into(bitmapView);
```

**Option 2**: Scaling image with `centerCrop` or `fitCenter`

> centerCrop() is a cropping technique that scales the image so that it
>   fills the requested bounds of the ImageView and then crops the extra.
>   The ImageView will be filled completely, but the entire image might
>   not be displayed.

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .centerCrop();

Glide.with(ctx)
    .asBitmap()
    .apply(myOptions)
    .load(url)
    .into(bitmapView);
```

> fitCenter() is a cropping technique that scales the image so that both
>   dimensions are equal to or less than the requested bounds of the
>   ImageView. The image will be displayed completely, but might not fill
>   the entire ImageView.

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
        .fitCenter();

    Glide.with(ctx)
        .asBitmap()
        .apply(myOptions)
        .load(url)
        .into(bitmapView);
```

**Option 3**: Mix both of these solutions

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .fitCenter() // or centerCrop
    .override(100, 100);

 Glide.with(ctx)
     .asBitmap()
     .apply(myOptions)
     .load(url)
     .into(bitmapView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Glide
    .with(ctx)
    .load(url)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this uses Kotlin's Extensions functions. Using the width and height of the image which makes it more efficient. In some cases you might need to add a multiplier to the width and height for better quality.

```
    fun ImageView.loadImage(uri: String) {

        this.post {

            val myOptions = RequestOptions()
               .override(this.width, this.height)
               .centerCrop()

            Glide
               .with(this.context)
               .load(uri)
               .apply(myOptions)
               .into(this)

        }

    }
```