# Reduce Image Quality on ImageView Android

Tags: android, api, imageview

I'm developing a wallpaper app where I'm displaying n number of images in a recyclerView from an API but the problem here is that the quality of the image is so high that it is taking time to load all the images into the recyclerView. So, how can I reduce the quality of the images so that they load as soon as I open the app.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to load the images on your rv?

Comment: I'm using the glide library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Compress and reduce Quality of image using Glide for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314383/how-to-compress-and-reduce-quality-of-image-using-glide-for-android)

Comment: Yes, the images quality is getting reduced, but.. still the images are taking time to load into the recycler view. The images which I loaded last time I ran the app are loading quickly but the rest are still taking lots of time. Any idea what would be the reason for that?

Comment: I think you need to read the glide documentation, there you can find how glide load images and why some take more time to load, remember that cache plays a important part. Also your rv implementation MAY need some improvement.

Comment: Sure. I'll definitely do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add glide library to your project and whatever the size you wanted to give you can add here : **override(X, Y)**

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .override(100, 100);
Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .apply(myOptions)
    .load(image_url)
    .into(bitmapView);
```

Comment: I tried your code and yes, it does reduces the quality of the images, but still the images are taking time to load. Some images which I loaded when I first ran the app are getting displayed quickly while the others are still taking time. Any Idea what would be the reason?

Comment: Could you try this one RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).override(100, 100);

Comment: I guess there was some problem with the API. I changed the API and now it works fine with the RequestOptions code which you shared. Thank you very much Rinki :)